# Jquery string and logical OR

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whats wrong with the below lines of code ...

Its keep complaing that systax error..at the like

```
if( (radioval === "undefined")  || (radioval === null) || (radioval === "null") ) {
```

complete condition in action

```
if($('#digitallogin').is(":checked")){
              var radioval = $("input[name=certificateradio]:checked").val();//its giving the string "user" 
                if( (radioval === "undefined")  || (radioval === null) || (radioval === "null") ) {   //this line 
                    $("#login_error").text("please select the signin certificate");
                        return false;
                 }

          }
```

[image]

Thanks for any Assistance.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici why that ?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici I put === for strict comparision.Though I tested with == also .

Comment: There is nothing wrong there.

Comment: @gdoron I would be happy If that is true,But firebug told me that its syntax erro

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle ? Or show us more code ?

Comment: There's no syntax error that I can see in your code. The syntax errors in your screenshot are in your *watchpoint* expressions.

Comment: @MichaelGeary If you're sure of that (I don't know Firebug), then it would make a good answer.

Comment: @MichaelGeary But even I entered the line eatch point it should show true/false..  but showing error.

Comment: I can't see the entire watchpoint panel in your screenshot - it seems to be scrolled off the edge - but those syntax error messages on the right side are referring to the watch expressions themselves. These errors have nothing to do with anything in your code. If you delete the watch expressions they will go away.

Comment: Updated with the pic of firebug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no syntax error in your code. If the code had a syntax error, there would be an error message in the Firebug console (not the Watch panel), and the code would not run at all. You'd never get to your breakpoint.

The syntax errors in your screenshot are in your *watch* expressions. Delete the watch expressions and those error messages will go away.

In your updated screenshot I can see what the syntax error is. Take a close look at your watch expression (reformatted here to avoid scrolling):

```
if(
    (radioval === "undefined")  ||
    (radioval === null) ||
    (radioval === "null")
)
```

That's not an expression, it's an `if` statement. If you want to use it as a watch expression, you need just the expression *inside* the `if` statement. That is, remove the `if(` and the final `)`.

Regarding the specific tests you're making, jQuery's `.val()` method does return `undefined` if there are no elements selected. Note that there is an error in the jQuery documentation: it says that `.val()` returns `null` when there are no matching elements. This is incorrect; it returns `undefined` in this case. Here is [the line of code in the jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e53a91909061c7a7280a274990db179b94db81b6/src/attributes.js#L184) that returns `undefined` (because it is a simple `return;` with no value).

But that is the `undefined` value, not the string `"undefined"`. You would test for this with `radioval === undefined`. Or you could use `radioval == null`. Note the `==` instead of `===`; this test matches both `null` and `undefined` values. That may be the safest bet, in case the jQuery team ever decides to change the code to match the documentation and start returning `null` instead of `undefined`. (An unlikely possibility, but you never know.) By testing `radioval == null` it would test against either value.

Comment: when I did'nt select any radio button val returns me undefined

Comment: @Baadshah `"undefined"` is very different from `undefined`. Can you confirm the problem goes away when you remove the breakpoints ?

Comment: @dystroy thanks for make me realize.How can I check undefined then ?

Comment: Remove the quotes... or simply `if (!radioval) {`.

Comment: @dystroy Thanks you .Let me try that

Comment: @Baadshah And what about the syntax problem and the breakpoints ? You should probably accept this answer (+1 to it from me anyway).

Comment: @dystroy I'm updating my post with new image and breakpoints ..will get it soon .

Comment: Updated with the pic of firebug.

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` returns a string value, `null` or an `Array` in case of a multiselect value, so you could try:

```
if (/null|undefined/i.test(radioval) || !radioval.length){ /*...*/ }
```

Since you seem to check for [one of] `$("input[name=certificateradio]")` being checked, it may also be sufficient to do

```
if( ( !$("input[name=certificateradio]:checked").length ) {
  $("#login_error").text("please select the signin certificate");
   return false;
}
```

Or even shorter

```
if( $('#digitallogin').is(":checked") && 
    !$("input[name=certificateradio]:checked").length ) {
  $("#login_error").text("please select the signin certificate");
  return false;
}
```

Comment: You're right. It can also return an array in case of a multiselect. Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if( (typeof radioval === "undefined")  || (radioval === null) || (radioval == "null") ) {
```

Comment: That would do something different and how is it supposed to solve a syntax error ?

Comment: @commit typeof is just used to open any closed generic type associate with any particular time at runtime.

Comment: @dystroy  typeof is just used to open any closed generic type associate with any particular time at runtime.

Comment: @dystroy That doesn't seems any syntax error in code, however it is perfect way to checking 'undefined' because typeof will return always string whether variable exist or not it will not fire exception.

Answer (score 0):

in the third comparison of radioval
   radioval == "null" and not === null

Comment: Why exactly ? Can you explain ?

Comment: === is a strictly comparison to a value associated with a data type.

Answer (score 0):

$("input[name=certificateradio]:checked").val(); returns undefined (typeof undefined === undefined) if it's unchecked or "on" (typeof "on" === string) if it's checked.

a small example:

```
<input name="certificateradio" type="checkbox" /> 
<button>run</button>

$("button").click(function(){
    console.log($("input[name=certificateradio]:checked").val());
    console.log(typeof $("input[name=certificateradio]:checked").val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x2uw4/1/

try to use:

```
if($("input[name=certificateradio]:checked").val() ==="on"){
   ...
}
```